# How to manually 'install' a command-line based Java application consisting of an executable and several auxiliary modules?

Tags: terminal, install, java

I'd like to use [Briss](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/), a Java application for cropping pdf files. The application consists of a compressed folder containing several Java .jar files. Presumably one of them is the executable, and the others are auxiliary modules that the executable uses. The application has a GUI, but is run from the Terminal by running the following command line:

```
java -jar briss-0.9.jar
```

How can I 'install' this application so that I can run it by typing the above command in a freshly opened Terminal window?

One way to do it would be to dump all the .jar files inside `/usr/local/bin`, but I'd rather not pollute the `bin` folder with a horde of files, and also I'd like to keep the files together, so that, for instance, the application can be easily and cleanly 'uninstalled'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the files to somewhere static such as ~/Applications, then add the following to your profile:

```
alias briss="java -jar /path/to/briss-0.9.jar"
```

Then you can run ‘briss’ from Terminal from anywhere.

You may need to create ~/Applications if you haven't used it before. Upon creation, macOS automatically gives the folder the Applications folder icon. The location of your profile depends on your shell — the default macOS shell is bash and the profile is `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion: When I open a new Terminal window and execute `cat .bash_profile`, the resulting output ends with the line `alias briss="java -jar ~/Applications/briss-0.9/briss-0.9.jar"`. However, running `briss` from the same Terminal window results in the following message: `-bash: briss: command not found`.

Comment: @Evan Have you restarted your shell, or sourced the profile again (`. ~/.bash_profile`)?